# How does the prophet of Islam respond to 'salat' he receives?

Tags: prophet-muhammad, salawat

It is said that each time you say peace be upon the prophet of Islam, this message is transmitted to him, he hears it and he respond to your Salam. If potentially, thousands of Muslims are saying this at the same time, how this process would work ?

Answer (score 3):

This is not a question we have an answer for.

After death,you basically go to a completely different life.. which could not follow our mind-limited physical laws..

It's all from the knowledge of 'ghayb which we shouldn't put our noses in.

Just like asking " How can Jibreel have 600 wings ?" or " How can Allah talk to us all on the day of judgment simultaneously?"

This is a **red line** which you shouldnt cross.

Comment: You just went from : this is not a question we have an answer for. To this is a red line which you shouldn't cross.

Comment: Yes, you do have the right to ask questions. But it's just the fact that we have limits. We don't have the right to ask everything.                                          A man asked Imam Malik (d. 179): "How did Allah make istiwa' on the throne?" Imam Malik inclined his head and was silent until the sweat of fever covered his brow, then he looked up and said: "Istiwa' is not unknown, the modality of it is inconceivable in the mind; but belief in it is obligatory, and inquiring about it is a heretical innovation. You are an innovator." And he gave orders for him to be taken out.

Comment: I'm referencing this just so you don't think I'm exaggerating or so.. Imam Malik called him an " innovator "  So don't try finding answers for these questions because they're from the shaitan and he wants to open for you a big door of suspicion in religion... and it probably won't stop at this point if you keep going on with these thoughts.      I'm just giving advice brother :) I might have made mistakes or so but this is what I've learnt and Im just passing knowledge 

Comment: Just a correction --> Being an innovator doesnt at all mean that person is going to hell.. It depends according to what that person has innovated.. like for example a lot of people (in the arab counties) celebrate the birthday of our prophet; which is clearly an innovation and its prohibited.. but that doesn't remove them from being muslims. But others could put innovations which contradict clear Quranic verses; that one is who goes to hell; as he denied the Quran using his mind philosophy ( implying he knows more than Allah ) , in that case he's a kafir.

Comment: I don't think you should ask. This question has a good comprehensive answer https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/38993/35830